# Convert Javascript String to specific format

Tags: javascript, date

I have this `String` :

```
var str = "Thu, 10 Apr 2014 09:19:08 +0000";
```

I would like to get this format : `"10 Apr 2014"`

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you trying to format time from a timestamp or just a bare string of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var str = "Thu, 10 Apr 2014 09:19:08 +0000";
    var d = new Date(str);
   var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var b=  d.getDate()+' '+month[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getFullYear();
    alert(b);
```

Check the result in
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkadeshwaran/u3NUL/)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on spaces and take the second to the fourth items and join:

```
var d = str.split(' ').slice(1, 4).join(' ');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7FuD6/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `substring()` method like this,

```
 var str = "Thu, 10 Apr 2014 09:19:08 +0000";
 var res = str.substring(5,15);
```

Comment: Yes, but there is no other way to do this using Date type ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Thu, 10 Apr 2014 09:19:08 +0000",
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    d = new Date(str);

d.getDate() + " " + months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();  //"10 Apr 2014"
```

The date string you have can be passed into the `Date` constructor to get a date object, `d`. The date object has various methods to that gives day, year, month, time etc. Since months are returned as an integer and we need the name, we use an array called `months`.

Comment: The Thom: Added some explanation.